# Problem With Saving PlayerPrefs On Exit Application

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a script in which after 4 hours, bonus level is unlocked. it works fine in unity editor but It doesn't work on android built. I guess there might be something wrong with *OnApplicationQuit()* but I tried *OnApplicationPause()* and *OnApplicationFocus()* either but none of them worked! I really don't know what to do! here is my script;

```
     using UnityEngine;
     using System.Collections;
     using System;
     using System.Globalization;
     
     public class Date : MonoBehaviour
     {
     DateTime currentDate;
     DateTime oldDate;
     public static bool bonus;

     void Start()
 {
     currentDate = System.DateTime.Now;

     var oldTimeString = PlayerPrefs.GetString("sysString", "10");

     if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(oldTimeString))
     {
         
         if(long.TryParse(oldTimeString, out var temp))
         {
             var oldDate = DateTime.FromBinary(temp);
             var difference = currentDate.Subtract(oldDate);
             if(difference.Hours>4)
             {
                 bonus=true;
             }
         }
     }
 }
      void OnApplicationPause(bool pauseStatus)
     {
        if(pauseStatus){
             PlayerPrefs.SetString("sysString", System.DateTime.Now.ToBinary().ToString());
             PlayerPrefs.Save();
        }

     }
 
 }
```

Comment: This is not C code. Please review your tags.

Comment: Are you building for IOS platform?

Comment: No It's for Android

Comment: This is also not `unityscript` which is a **deprecated** JavaScript flavour-like language previously used in Unity ... it was long replaced by `c#`

Answer (score 1):

Add `Application.runInBackground = false;` to an `Awake` method or at the beginning of your `Start` method and use `difference.TotalHours` instead of `Hours`. The latter will only return the hour part of the date time.

Comment: Thanks man! it was my fault! there were two OnApplicationQuit() on one scene and that was the problem, but your advice for using TotalHours was really helpful! one more thing; this mechanism is based on the time player quit the game, so every time he starts the game the *difference* restarts. is there any way to set it based on bonus level not OnApplicationQuit()?

Comment: I didn't get the question. You want bonus level to be unlocked 4 hours after the last bonus level have been played?

Comment: Yes exactly! is it possible by changing this script or should  I write a new script?

Comment: Well, save the time by using the script inside ```OnApplicationPause``` every time they played the bonus level, not when they close the game.